# How to capitalize information within a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Example: I have a dataframe like this:

```
pokemon1<-c('abra', 'kadabra', 'alakazam')
evolution<-c('1st', '2nd', '3rd')
pokemon<-as.data.frame(pokemon1, evolution )
```

It looks very nice but I'd need to capitalize the names of the pokemon. How do I do that?

I tried:
`pokemon<-toupper(pokemon)`, but this also capitalized the structural part of the code, turning the table into a line of text that says: "[1] "C("ABRA", "KADABRA", "ALAKAZAM")""

Comment: Simply use `pokemon$pokemon1=toupper(pokemon$pokemon1)` ?

Comment: Except it doesnt work on my original data for some reason.... I guess its not a dataframe after all but some sort of vector with multiple rows?

Comment: Only you can answer this question as we don't have the data sorry